# Add spacing around connector label in Microsoft Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

How can I add some spacing around connector label in Microsoft Visio?

Example (text of interest in red rectangle):

[image]

should be:

[image]

Adding spaces in the text only works for adding margin on the left, but doesn't seem to work for right margin.

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the connector text, then at the far right-hand end

menu **Insert** -> **Symbol** -> **More Symbols** -> **Special Characters**

and select **Non-breaking space**.